# How to read values by foreign key

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm fairly new to Laravel and React. I have 3 tables called students, users and projects. Each project has 1 student, 1 supervisor and 2 examiners (supervisors and examiners are users) assigned to it. I want to try to fetch the names of the student and user from the respective tables and display them.

My Project.php

```
protected $with =['projectStudent', 'projectSupervisor', 'projectExaminer1', 'projectExaminer2'];
public function projectStudent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Student', 'student_id', 'student_id');
}

public function projectSupervisor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'supervisor_id', 'id');
}

public function projectExaminer1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'examiner1_id', 'id');
}

public function projectExaminer2()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'examiner2_id', 'id');
}
```

My ProjectController.php

```
public function index()
{
    return ProjectResource::collection(
        Project::query()->with('projectStudent')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5)
    );
}
```

My Projects.jsx

```
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
const [paginate, setPaginate] = useState(1);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const {setNotification} = useStateContext();

useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();
}, [paginate])

const handlePaginate = (direction) => {
    setPaginate(prevPage => prevPage + direction)
}
function classNames(...classes) {
    return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}
const getProjects = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axiosClient.get(`/projects?page=${paginate}`)
        .then(({data}) => {
            setLoading(false);
            setProjects(data.data);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        })
}
```

I want to get name of the student and the names of supervisor and examiner but project.projectStudent.name returns undefined.

When I try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.data, null, 2))` the data, I get

```
[

{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Stock Market Prediction",
    "student_id": "SW0102469",
    "supervisor_id": 18,
    "examiner1_id": 12,
    "examiner2_id": 33
  }
]
```

And this is my projectResource.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProjectResource extends JsonResource
{
    public static $wrap = false;
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'student_id' => $this->student_id,
            'supervisor_id' => $this->supervisor_id,
            'examiner1_id' => $this->examiner1_id,
            'examiner2_id' => $this->examiner2_id,
//            'start_date' => $this->start_date->format('Y-m-d'),
//            'end_date' => $this->end_date->format('Y-m-d'),
//            'duration' => $this->duration,
//            'status' => $this->status,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `console.log()` the result data ?

Comment: console logging the data outputs the values that are already in the projects table which are the title, id, student_id and the other 3 id's from users

Comment: Can you add the output to your question ?

Comment: I've added the `console.log(data)` output

Comment: @Ram could you post the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.data, null, 2))`? This should make things more clear.

Comment: I've done as you asked

Comment: As I understand it, that array is the projects array that you want to iterate to get `project.projectStudent.name` from, right? If that's the case, it seems the back is not including that data, for some reason. Perhaps you forgot to include it when generating the data?

Comment: what is inside ProjectResource.php ?

Comment: I've included the ProjectResource.php